# Object value in array is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to get value from array object. But if I call it directly I get undefined. I write example and code below.

So I create array of objects. Example:

```
const convertedDataTest = [ [ { S1: [Array],
      C1: [Array],
      S2: [Array],
      C2: [Array],
      S3: [Array],
      C3: [Array],
      S4: [Array],
      C4: [Array],
      S5: [Array],
      C5: [Array],
      CLASS: [Array] } ],
  [ { S1: [Array],
      C1: [Array],
      S2: [Array],
      C2: [Array],
      S3: [Array],
      C3: [Array],
      S4: [Array],
      C4: [Array],
      S5: [Array],
      C5: [Array],
      CLASS: [Array] } ],
  [ { S1: [Array],
      C1: [Array],
      S2: [Array],
      C2: [Array],
      S3: [Array],
      C3: [Array],
      S4: [Array],
      C4: [Array],
      S5: [Array],
      C5: [Array],
      CLASS: [Array] } ] ]
```

If I call array value

```
console.log(convertedDataTest[1]);
```

I see everything, but if I call object value:

```
console.log(convertedDataTest[1].CLASS);
```

I get undefined.

Also I create this array of object with map method and a few functions.

```
function arrayMaker(length, val) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i == val - 1 || (i == 0 && val == 0)) arr.push(1);
        else arr.push(0);
    }

    return arr;
}

function convertData(data) {
    const convertedData = data.map(item => {
        return [
            {
                S1: arrayMaker(4, item.S1),
                C1: arrayMaker(13, item.C1),
                S2: arrayMaker(4, item.S2),
                C2: arrayMaker(13, item.C2),
                S3: arrayMaker(4, item.S3),
                C3: arrayMaker(13, item.C3),
                S4: arrayMaker(4, item.S4),
                C4: arrayMaker(13, item.C4),
                S5: arrayMaker(4, item.S5),
                C5: arrayMaker(13, item.C5),
                CLASS: arrayMaker(10, item.CLASS)
            }
        ];
    });
    return convertedData;
}
const convertedData = convertData(data);
const convertedDataTest = convertData(dataTest);
```

Example of data:

```
[
    { "S1": 4, "C1": 11, "S2": 2, "C2": 9, "S3": 1, "C3": 5, "S4": 3, "C4": 9, "S5": 2, "C5": 7, "CLASS": 1 },
    { "S1": 4, "C1": 5, "S2": 2, "C2": 3, "S3": 1, "C3": 1, "S4": 3, "C4": 10, "S5": 2, "C5": 6, "CLASS": 0 },
    { "S1": 3, "C1": 8, "S2": 2, "C2": 7, "S3": 2, "C3": 3, "S4": 3, "C4": 7, "S5": 1, "C5": 12, "CLASS": 1 },
    { "S1": 3, "C1": 12, "S2": 4, "C2": 8, "S3": 4, "C3": 7, "S4": 3, "C4": 3, "S5": 1, "C5": 6, "CLASS": 0 },
    { "S1": 1, "C1": 2, "S2": 2, "C2": 12, "S3": 1, "C3": 8, "S4": 1, "C4": 13, "S5": 3, "C5": 1, "CLASS": 0 },
    { "S1": 2, "C1": 7, "S2": 2, "C2": 5, "S3": 4, "C3": 9, "S4": 4, "C4": 6, "S5": 1, "C5": 9, "CLASS": 1 },
    { "S1": 2, "C1": 2, "S2": 1, "C2": 13, "S3": 2, "C3": 13, "S4": 4, "C4": 3, "S5": 4, "C5": 13, "CLASS": 3 },
    { "S1": 4, "C1": 10, "S2": 4, "C2": 11, "S3": 1, "C3": 10, "S4": 2, "C4": 9, "S5": 4, "C5": 1, "CLASS": 1 },
    { "S1": 4, "C1": 2, "S2": 3, "C2": 10, "S3": 4, "C3": 7, "S4": 4, "C4": 10, "S5": 2, "C5": 6, "CLASS": 1 },
    { "S1": 2, "C1": 8, "S2": 4, "C2": 13, "S3": 3, "C3": 8, "S4": 3, "C4": 2, "S5": 4, "C5": 2, "CLASS": 2 }
]
```

Comment: JavaScript arrays start at 0, not 1.  `convertedDataTest[0].CLASS` works.

Comment: It doesn't work. You can try to take any data point from 0 to 9. ```convertedDataTest[0-9].CLASS```

Comment: @RaulisRadziukas [no, it does work](https://jsbin.com/hotiberare/edit?js,console). You have a single element in the array, so if you take the *second* one, it doesn't

Comment: Does your code *really* look like that `const` declaration, or are you fetching that content from an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating an array of objects. You are creating an array of array of objects within your `.map(...)`.

`map()` creates a new array with the elements returned, and you are returning in your map this:

```
return [ // Returning an array.
    {...}
];
```

So the final array will be this:

```
[
    [ // The array returned in map
        {S1: ..., CLASS: ...}
    ],
    [ // The array returned in map
        {S1: ..., CLASS: ...}
    ]
]
```

Note how each array element is not an object, but another array containing an object.

You must change your `.map()` to this:

```
function convertData(data) {
    const convertedData = data.map(item => {
        return { // Note how I removed the [
            S1: arrayMaker(4, item.S1),
            C1: arrayMaker(13, item.C1),
            S2: arrayMaker(4, item.S2),
            C2: arrayMaker(13, item.C2),
            S3: arrayMaker(4, item.S3),
            C3: arrayMaker(13, item.C3),
            S4: arrayMaker(4, item.S4),
            C4: arrayMaker(13, item.C4),
            S5: arrayMaker(4, item.S5),
            C5: arrayMaker(13, item.C5),
            CLASS: arrayMaker(10, item.CLASS)
        };  // Note how I removed the ]
    });
    return convertedData;
}
```

Note how I removed the `[` and `]` and I just return the object that you want.

Comment: @RaulisRadziukas please include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You are giving us contradicting and incomplete information here.

Comment: Thank you Jorge. That was exactly the problem :)

Comment: Yeah, I know, because I actually read your question, not like others :-) I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
const convertedDataTest = [ { S1: [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ],
    C1: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    S2: [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
    C2: [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    S3: [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
    C3: [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    S4: [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
    C4: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
    S5: [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
    C5: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    CLASS: [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] } ]
```

convertedDataTest is an array which have only 1 object which is available at index 0. So when you try to get value from index 1, it returned undefined.

You can get class array by this line

```
convertedDataTest[0].CLASS
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. It's just an example there are 10 objects inside this array.

Comment: That's not an answer to the problem he is having. The problem is how he `map()` the array. The correct array he shared is below, where it says "example of data".

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález in fairness, the problem is that OP wasn't really clear and the sample given didn't represent the actual data.

Comment: @VLAZ If you read the entire question, from top to bottom, instead of rushing when you read the `console.log(convertedDataTest[1].CLASS);` part, you can read how he creates the array and the xample data, so you notice that is not a single element array. Keep calm and read the question from top to bottom xD

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález but it was OP who misrepresented his dataset. When you read a question, you expect it to be truthful and to have an MVCE. This one is incorrect and doesn't have an MVCE. The onus is not on us to try to guess which of the conflicting data is *actually* correct. For all we know the mapping presented could be wrong or the data could be coming asynchronously, yet OP expects it to be synchronous. As it stands, the question is not good and you shouldn't be blaming the readers for that.

Comment: @VLAZ I think that you don't see the part where it says "I create this array with this map and this 10 elements array" then. There's no misleading information in the question, or at least in the entire question. Maybe the first part can be misleading, but fixed if you read the question. The problem here is that people rush to answer instantly instead of reading the entire question. Reading the entire question fixes this, and is obvious that the answerer don't read the entire question as he don't noticed the example data. I think that the problem is from both users actually , OP and answerer.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I did see that part and it contradicts the data presented. Again, this is a bad question because of it. We have quality standards on SO and this question is breaking them. The failure in miscommunication between the question and answerer is *directly* the fault of the question. In truth, this shouldn't have even been answered without OP correcting the question.

Comment: @VLAZ I guess you were one of those that also don't read the entire question then ;-) Is not that hard to waste a couple of minutes more to read a question completely and actually understand what is happening. And you cannot tell me that you read the entire question and still think that the array was of 1 element instead of 10... I know that you are smart (not kidding) and reading the entire question clarifies what is happening actually. I'm still saying that the fault is from both, the one that writes contradicting information and the one that don't reads the entire question.

Comment: You cannot defend a position where "I only read part of your question and got it wrong! is completely your fault!" As you said, in SO we have quality standards, and one is to read and understand carefully what problem the OP has, hence the fault is from both parts. Is a bad question because of contradicting info, but also a bad answer because of rushing. Quality standards go both ways :P

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I'm the person who voted to close this because it was a bad question. And reading the entirety of it showed me a bad one. Since OP couldn't even show proper data, I couldn't be sure if the array was flattened after the mapping, or if even was an async operation. Again, bad question. My response was not to guess what *might* be correct or not - after all, OP showed that the information he showed is not to be trusted. Instead of trying to blame everybody for "not reading", you should spend some more time making sure the content is actually of quality worthy of reading.

Comment: @VLAZ Yep, I've done it and got the problem instantly. I helped this user and that's what I'm here for. Maybe we have different ways of finding solutions to problems I guess. EDIT: I also vote close a lot of questions, but vote-closing this one is being like a grammar-nazi when you actually know the solution to his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be wrapping the data in an extra array, so `convertedData[0][0].CLASS` would be defined. If you remove the array from the return statement in the `convertData` function, as below, `convertedData[0].CLASS` will work.

```js
var data = [
    { "S1": 4, "C1": 11, "S2": 2, "C2": 9, "S3": 1, "C3": 5, "S4": 3, "C4": 9, "S5": 2, "C5": 7, "CLASS": 1 },
    { "S1": 4, "C1": 5, "S2": 2, "C2": 3, "S3": 1, "C3": 1, "S4": 3, "C4": 10, "S5": 2, "C5": 6, "CLASS": 0 },
    { "S1": 3, "C1": 8, "S2": 2, "C2": 7, "S3": 2, "C3": 3, "S4": 3, "C4": 7, "S5": 1, "C5": 12, "CLASS": 1 },
    { "S1": 3, "C1": 12, "S2": 4, "C2": 8, "S3": 4, "C3": 7, "S4": 3, "C4": 3, "S5": 1, "C5": 6, "CLASS": 0 },
    { "S1": 1, "C1": 2, "S2": 2, "C2": 12, "S3": 1, "C3": 8, "S4": 1, "C4": 13, "S5": 3, "C5": 1, "CLASS": 0 },
    { "S1": 2, "C1": 7, "S2": 2, "C2": 5, "S3": 4, "C3": 9, "S4": 4, "C4": 6, "S5": 1, "C5": 9, "CLASS": 1 },
    { "S1": 2, "C1": 2, "S2": 1, "C2": 13, "S3": 2, "C3": 13, "S4": 4, "C4": 3, "S5": 4, "C5": 13, "CLASS": 3 },
    { "S1": 4, "C1": 10, "S2": 4, "C2": 11, "S3": 1, "C3": 10, "S4": 2, "C4": 9, "S5": 4, "C5": 1, "CLASS": 1 },
    { "S1": 4, "C1": 2, "S2": 3, "C2": 10, "S3": 4, "C3": 7, "S4": 4, "C4": 10, "S5": 2, "C5": 6, "CLASS": 1 },
    { "S1": 2, "C1": 8, "S2": 4, "C2": 13, "S3": 3, "C3": 8, "S4": 3, "C4": 2, "S5": 4, "C5": 2, "CLASS": 2 }
];


function arrayMaker(length, val) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i == val - 1 || (i == 0 && val == 0)) arr.push(1);
        else arr.push(0);
    }

    return arr;
}

function convertData(data) {
    const convertedData = data.map(item => {
        return {
                S1: arrayMaker(4, item.S1),
                C1: arrayMaker(13, item.C1),
                S2: arrayMaker(4, item.S2),
                C2: arrayMaker(13, item.C2),
                S3: arrayMaker(4, item.S3),
                C3: arrayMaker(13, item.C3),
                S4: arrayMaker(4, item.S4),
                C4: arrayMaker(13, item.C4),
                S5: arrayMaker(4, item.S5),
                C5: arrayMaker(13, item.C5),
                CLASS: arrayMaker(10, item.CLASS)
            };
    });
    return convertedData;
}
const convertedData = convertData(data);

console.log(convertedData[0].CLASS);
```